# Storing an image from a url into a bitmap with memory stream

Tags: c#

Iam trying to store an image in to a bitmap from a URL, I have the following code:

```
public static List<Bitmap> Images = new List<Bitmap>();

using (systemcore.client)
{
    using (var response = await systemcore.client.GetAsync("http://i.imgur.com/BsPzIfs.png"))
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(memoryStream);
            Images.Add(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

`systemcore.client` is just a `httpclient`

When I try to run this, I get an error saying:

> Parameter is not valid

How can I store an image in to a bitmap from the memory stream?

Comment: I may be a little confused here, but it appears as if you are not doing anything with the data from the `response` You simply instantiate a `MemoryStream` then a `Bitmap` and add a blank memory stream to said bitmap. You might want to feed the data from the response to the `MemoryStream`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what `systemcore.client` is, so can't really help you with that. However, this is how you would do it with a normal `HttpClient`:

```
async Task<List<Bitmap>> getImages()
{
    var images = new List<Bitmap>();
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://i.imgur.com/BsPzIfs.png");
        var bitmap = new Bitmap();
        if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                var memStream = new MemoryStream();
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
                memStream.Position = 0;
                images.Add(new Bitmap(memStream);
            }
        }
    }
    return images;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something very similar, here is the code (this works for me):
Firstly I have a function that gets the byte sequence of an image (of course you have to use the url of a single image).
Then i call the function to get the byte list.
I create a MemoryStream object using its constructor to load into it the bytes. Then get the Bitmap using the MemoryStream.

```
byte[] GetImage(string url)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (dataStream == null)
                return null;
            using (var sr = new BinaryReader(dataStream))
            {
                byte[] bytes = sr.ReadBytes(100000000);

                return bytes;
            }
        }
    }
```

The call:

```
byte[] image = GetImage(selectedUrl);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(image))
{

    Image img = new Image.FromStream(ms);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);
}
```

I used an Image object because I'm not sure the Bitmap constructor can read a MemoryStream object (can read a Stream object, btw).