# Picture retrieval from Active Directory c#

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, ldap

[image]

I am particularly new with LDAP and wanted to know if there is a way we could know what information has been filled in the active directory for a particular domain.

For example I am trying to obtain the image of the employees of an organization using

```
var bytes = directoryEntry.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value;
```

But this returns null. Now I want to know if the image exists and maybe I am not getting it the right way or there is no image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
var data = user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value as byte[];

if (data != null)
    using (var s = new MemoryStream(data))
        return Bitmap.FromStream(s);
else
    foreach (PropertyValueCollection p in user.Properties)
        Trace.WriteLine(p.PropertyName);
```

Double-check the property, it might be `jpegPhoto`

```
byte[] data = user.Properties["jpegPhoto"].Value as byte[];
```

Source:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02690cfa-c2c1-43d7-9f82-7d210cb86267/c-code-to-add-and-retrieve-user-photos-from-active-directory?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I am getting the value in the byte array (attached is the image in the question). How can I display it on html page?

Comment: Save the image somewhere `Bitmap.FromStream(s).Save(path);`, or manage the response to only respond with images.  if you are still having issues, then open a new question as it is unrelated to the original question.

Comment: Check this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054639/storing-an-image-from-a-url-into-a-bitmap-with-memory-stream

Comment: Thanks it worked! But the image pixel resolution is not good! :( any way to make  it better?

Comment: Accept the answer and open a new question, but check this first https://stackoverflow.com/a/42113158/643500

Answer (score 1):

What about convert to base64?

```
var bytes = directoryEntry.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value;

if (buffer != null)
var base64Thumb = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```