# Failing to read image from Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, image, active-directory, directorysearcher

I am trying to read user image from Active Directory in C#. I am new to this and I have tried many online solutions.

In most cases they have used bitmap but for me somehow bitmap is not working as it fails to find reference even though I have added `System.Drawing.Common`. So I have tried another way but still I couldn't get it done. I am able to get the data in `byte[]` but somehow I'm unable to pass it to a `memoryStream`.

Here is my code:

```
private User LookUpUserInActiveDirectory(string emailId)
{
    User ldapUser = new User();

    try
    {
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, this.activeDirectoryConfiguration.PrincipalContextName, this.activeDirectoryConfiguration.PrincipalContextContainer, this.activeDirectoryConfiguration.UserName, this.activeDirectoryConfiguration.Password))
        {
            using (UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(ctx))
            {
                userPrincipal.EmailAddress = emailId;

                // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal     
                using (PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal))
                {
                    using (UserPrincipal results = (UserPrincipal)new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal).FindOne())
                    {
                        if (results != null)
                        {
                            // DirectoryEntry de = results.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                            DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry)results.GetUnderlyingObject();

                            // DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry)results.GetUnderlyingObject();
                            PropertyValueCollection collection = directoryEntry.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"];

                            if (collection.Value != null && collection.Value is byte[])
                            {
                                byte[] thumbnailInBytes = (byte[])collection.Value;
                                // return new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(thumbnailInBytes));
                            }

                            ldapUser.Name = results.DisplayName;
                            ldapUser.EmailId = results.EmailAddress;
                                   
                            using (DirectorySearcher dsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher())
                            {
                                dsSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=*)(mail=" + ldapUser.EmailId + "))";
                                SearchResult res = dsSearcher.FindOne();
                                using(DirectoryEntry user=new DirectoryEntry(res.Path))
                                {
                                    byte[] data = user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value as byte[];
                                    //if (data != null)
                                    //{
                                    //    using(MemoryStream s= new MemoryStream(data))
                                    //    {
                                    //        Bitmap.FormStream(s);
                                    //    }
                                    //}

                                    var fs = new MemoryStream();
                                    var wr = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                                    wr.Write(data);
                                    wr.Close();
                                    Console.WriteLine(fs);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ldapUser = null;
            }

            return ldapUser;

        }
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287037/picture-retrieval-from-active-directory-c-sharp

Comment: tried ... bitmap somehow doesnt work for me . I have added the reference but I'm still unable to use it .

Comment: What exact exception are you getting when using bitmap?

Comment: @oldovets the bitmap works fine for me now . I think it was the issue with my VS. Do you know how can we save the image  in bitmap to my local .

Comment: @TJ32 bitmap class has Save method which can save image to a file or a stream